# Where do I have to place the code returned by Google oAuth after I grant access to an installed application, using PHP?

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, google-oauth

This has been a nightmare to get right for the past few days. First I was struggling with redirect_uri_mismatch errors, or bad requests, but now that I thought I nailed it, I'm getting this message from Google after clicking the "Allow" button in the consent screen :

**Please copy this code, switch to your application and paste it there**

Where exactly do I need to paste this code? I'm using PHP in a web server, I went to the "Other" application type when creating the credentials, because I read that this was preferred if I didn't want my users to keep getting that auth link.

I can't seem to find a concrete example of how to do this, I got it working this far by grabbing bits from here and there, but this one I just can't figure it out.

https://gist.github.com/andruxnet/0f7fe237730c13846a690da12935a708

I'm using a file client_secret.json that I downloaded from Google's oAuth credentials screen, it looks like this:

```
{"installed":{"client_id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com","project_id":"my-project-id","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_secret":"xxxxxxxxxxx","redirect_uris":["urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob","http://localhost"]}}
```

Anyone knows what else I need to do or where to put that code returned from Google after the consent screen?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the answer here does not use PHP, I still think it's worth to add it here as it's the only complete working example of how to update a youtube video without displaying the consent screen to the user, at least I wasn't able to find a concrete working example.

I ended up using the Javascript library, I still wasn't able to find a single complete example, not even in the library docs, nor Google's, it took taking pieces of code from here and there, and connecting the dots.

First thing to do is to create the credentials, we do this by going to Google developer console, and under Credentials we create a new OAuth Client ID, choosing Web Application and adding our domain to the Authorized JavaScript origins field - eg. http://www.example.com

The only information we will need from these credentials is the Client ID, so we copy it and paste it in the Javascript file below.

Here's the HTML part, where we also load the API library:

```
<input type="button" id="make-private" value="private" /> Make video private
<input type="button" id="make-public" value="public" /> Make video public
Current privacy status: <span id="current-status"></span>
<script type="text/javascript" src="update.js"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=googleApiClientReady"></script>
```

This is the Javascript code to make it happen - update.js in the code above, remember to update with your own client ID: https://gist.github.com/andruxnet/2efe7898f5cd9722e0d42b71fce5d183

The relevant Javascript code, once we figure out the authentication part that can be found in several places online, is this piece of code:

```
// we first grab the video resource from Youtube, using youtube video id
var request = gapi.client.youtube.videos.list({
    id: 'youtubevideoid',
    part: 'status'
});

// once we get the video resource, we update the status and 
// run the update method
request.execute(function(response) {
    // since we looked for a video id, we only got one result - the first 
    // and only item in the array of result items
    video = response.result.items[0];

    // set the privacy status to one of public, private or unlisted
    video.status.privacyStatus = 'private';

    // prepare the update with the new privacy status
    var updateRequest = gapi.client.youtube.videos.update({
        part: 'status',
        fields: 'status',
        resource: video
    });

    // execute the update - I didn't see this part in the API documentation, 
    // I found it somewhere else in SO as part of another question, although 
    // I should've figured it out by looking at the first list() method above
    updateRequest.execute();
});
```

I hope this saves someone's time in the future as it would have saved my own.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I see disinformation, go and check this link:

> https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app#example

There you have many examples of what you are requesting, anyway the code you are receiving from google is the Auth Code which allows you to authenticate the client (The `Google_client->authenticate(AuthCode)` created in you php app to be more exact), after that you can start using their services with Accesstoken or RefreshTokens depending on what type of connection you requested to generete the perms.

I hope this comment help you a bit with the nightmare of developing Google Services :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Really I don't see why disinformation, I provided my secret json and all relevant code, and asked a very simple question: where to place that code returned after the consent screen? I did read that link you provided, in fact I read a lot of information but I'm still somehow missing the answer, your link is for a web app, and I want to use the "other" app, I had already made this work using web app but I really want to use "other" app type because of what I mentioned of not wanting my users to keep clicking the auth link

Comment: although I had already tried adding the code to the authenticate method as you suggested, the page didn't load for some reason, so now that you mentioned that it does help me a lot to try that route, I probably need to tweak the code a while to make that work, if not I'll just use web app credentials and be done with it... thanks a lot for taking the time to answer, sorry if I sounded rude in my previous comment, that's not what I meant 

Comment: It's my fault don't worry, i didn't check the git's link, i can't check it now, but just clicking the auth link for one time and storing the refresh token in a database or something would mean a big problem?The user would know even what services are you going to use in order to know if they really want to give you access.
Using a Web app is really easy to make it works, i don't know what could be the problem anyways.

Comment: I don't know if this is going to be useful to you or even if you already have it, but here you have a playgroung from Google to test tokens, authentication tokens and api requests:

https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Comment: I guess not, I could store the token in a temp file, don't want to mess around with the database as those changes mean quite a different workflow to get deployed... so then that way would work the same for my users as if I was using "other" app credentials? you mean using web app credentials, right?

Comment: yes, I already checked the playground, saw some videos, but didn't relate to what I was trying to do... the users don't need to even see what the app uses as the app will do that using the company's YouTube account, they'd be allowing access using that account and not theirs - that's another reason I was looking for a non web app way

Comment: It depends on what kind of app are you developing to choose between

- Server-side webs (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps)
- Client-side webs (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/client-side-web-apps)
- Installed Apps (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps)

If as you are saying it is going to be a Web Service anmd you can store the tokens i would go for the first one.